# Is it a bug that the Health App in the iOS11 upgrade 'forgets' your last place in the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

On iOS 10 - I could regularly enter the health app to enter my weight each day. Each day the weight graph would come up when I opened the app and I could enter my data with a single tap.

On iOS 11 - the health app 'forgets' that I was last at the weight graph, and when you open it goes to the health app home screen. This means two more taps to get to the weight graph, which I didn't have to do on iOS10.

Is there a way to fix this? It seems to be a feature regression.

My question is: **Is it a bug that the Health App in the iOS11 upgrade 'forgets' your last place in the app?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, yes it is a bug (although some may split hairs and call it a poor implementation).

In detail:

When you close any app it initially remains in a 'background' state. If you re-open it whilst it is still in the background state it will appear as if it had never been closed - with the same views open.

However iOS cannot leave apps in this state forever as it will run out of memory. When memory gets low (because you open other apps for example) background apps get 'suspended'. If you re-open it whilst it is suspended it will restart from scratch and by default show its 'home' view.

**However** there is a process called 'state restoration' that allows developers to bring a suspended app back to the same view as when it was last used (this typically takes a second or two, which is why apps sometimes seem to hesitate when you re-open them). This process has been broken in the update of the Health App which is why you are now seeing the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

here (iOS 11.0.2), when I reopen Health it opens in the last used window.

Comment: Ok - on 11.02 I can totally replicate the opposite behaviour